# Text is absolutely positioned but hides the relative image beneath it

Tags: html, css

So, in my HTML, I've put an Image which is responsive (changes size when browser window is changed). Now, on the top of it, I want to put my title (or you can say text). But the image is only appeared as a strip. It is displayed as a whole when you re-size the window very small. And when I change my text's position to absolute over the image which position is relative, everything disappears.

Here's my HTML:

```
<style>
.large-header {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    background: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    z-index: 1;
}

.candh_container .large-header {
    background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/vkfDo1I.jpg');
}

.main-title {
    /* position: absolute; */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;

}

.container_candh .main-title {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 4.2em;
    font-family:Montserrat;

}
</style>

<div class="candh_container">
    <div class="large-header">
         <h1 class="main-title">Candh Inc.</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ysksx5nu/

Comment: So do you want to show the whole image scaled to full width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that you used your image as a background, so it won't take any space. You have to scale the image itself to 100% width, and specify no height, so the ratio is kept.

```
<style>
.bg_image {
    width: 100%;
}

.candh_container {
    position: relative;
}

.main_title {
    position: absolute;
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0px;
}
</style>

<div class="candh_container">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/vkfDo1I.jpg" class="bg_image" />
    <h1 class="main_title">Candh Inc.</h1>
</div>
```

Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/ysksx5nu/1/

Comment: but, what if the user is on mobile? If we scale the window narrower, the image is becoming shorter! what can I do for having the image stick to the bottom and then re-size ?

Comment: You can specify a `min-height` to the image, see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ysksx5nu/2/

Comment: Thanks for helping, just there is a last question I want to ask. When I create a new div, say a rectangle, why there is space b/w the image and the rectangle and what can I do to solve it ? thanks again! Here's the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ysksx5nu/3/

Comment: @candh: The problem is, that the h1 tag has a margin (set it to 0) and you have to set the image's display to block, because the default (inline) adds a margin to that also. See fiddle: jsfiddle.net/ysksx5nu/4

Comment: hey, so I've been experimenting and looks like I'm in a fix once again :P Here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hbok6cpL/
So, if you see the full-screen result, and re-size the window, you will see that the image is not centering itself and just staying in position! can I do something to keep the tower always in center? Thanks

Comment: @candh, it's because you use background: cover; It will strech the image to the parent's width OR height. Try to decrease your browser's height and see the result. I think it's not the best to use cover mode here.

Comment: hey, @Fenistil I've reached my question limit actually, but I want some help with jQuery waypoints, see the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/4FNFW/133/ you see that the section I want to animate is already there (which it shouldn't be) at first and then it does the animation after a sec.

Comment: I'm actually trying to mimic this template http://tympanus.net/Freebies/HalcyonDaysTemplate/ you can clearly see that the section after the image, the text in it is not there at first but it fadeInLeft when we scroll over to it, that is what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: The problem, that they are hiding every element with `visibility: hidden;` (see wp1,2,3... classes) and then set them visible again in FadeInLeft class. Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4FNFW/142/